# AJAX request successful, but it fails to display data as intended. Instead, I get an "GET 404 NOT FOUND" error

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

Everything seems to be working fine apart from the fact that the data does not get displayed in the browser. When I check the console, the data has been received, it just does not display.

```
'use strict';

const btn = document.querySelector('.btn-country');
const countriesContainer = document.querySelector('.countries');

const getCountryData = function (country) {
 
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${country}`);
  request.send(); 

  request.addEventListener('load', function () {

    const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(data);

    const html = ` 
         <article class="country">
        <img class="country__img" src="${data.flag}" />
        <div class="country__data">
            <h3 class="country__name">${data.name}</h3>
            <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
            <p class="country__row"><span></span>${(
              +data.population / 1000000
            ).toFixed(1)}</p>
            <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${data.languages}</p>
            <p class="country__row"><span></span>${data.currencies}</p>
        </div>
        </article>`;
    countriesContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    **//undefined:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/16-Asynchronous/starter/undefined 404 (Not Found) - this is the error I get, it is In the line ABOVE**
    countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1;
  });
};

getCountryData('portugal');
getCountryData('usa');
getCountryData('slovakia');
```

Answer (score 0):

request.open('GET', 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/' + country);

Comment: does not work. I am trying to use template literal so I will get data for any country pass into the function...

Answer (score 0):

i have similar task and this worked for me

```
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/Sweden');
    request.send();

    request.addEventListener('load', function () {
      const [data] = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log(data);

      const html = `
      <article class="country">
      <img class="country__img" src="${data.flags.png}" />
      <div class="country__data">
        <h3 class="country__name">${data.name}</h3>
        <h4 class="country__region">${data.region}</h4>
        <p class="country__row"><span></span>${(
          +data.population / 1000000
        ).toFixed(1)} people</p>
        <p class="country__row"><span>️</span>${data.languages.swe}</p>
        <p class="country__row"><span></span>${data.currencies.SEK.name}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
    `;

      countriesContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
      countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1;
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).